# wordpress: session_id different in functions.php compared to all other *.php files

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I am using php sessions in wordpress.  If I print the session_id from any of several custom php pages I have made, it is the same session_id (so I can access _SESSION variables from any of these pages).  However, if I try to read a session variable in my functions.php file (for shortcode mapping), I cannot access the _SESSION variables because the session_id is different in this file (functions.php) only.  It seems the session is getting unset when running the functions.php file (I don't see anywhere where this is getting done).  I am trying to figure out how to set a global session so all of my files can set/read session variables.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Using `$_SESSION` in WordPress is a bad idea.  WordPress attempts to be stateless, and sessions are a pain to make work properly. I would *strongly* recommend you move to using `$_COOKIE` to store your data, and leverage the many articles that provide instruction on how to use cookies in WP.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because wordpress is either using a different cookie name, or different cookie settings.

What you want to do is make sure you are on the same domain (you can prefix the domain with a dot to set a cross domain cookie) and are using the same cookie path.

Comment: Thanks Ruben... can you elaborate more on when/where I prefix the domains?  Do I do this when starting a session, or when setting a session variable?